# Image in ImageView doesn't fits completely android

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I am using an custom Imageview library to Zoom on pinch and double tap.

I set a good resolution image ( 2263 x 3468 ) to the Imageview , but it doen't gets fully fit in to it .

There in some blank space in upper and lower part (height is not fully adjusted )

I tried every available options including ( fitXY , matrix,centreCrop etc ) noting worked

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lay_next"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity{

    Intent intent_menu;
    Matrix imageMatrix;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);


            ImageViewTouch mImage = (ImageViewTouch) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            mImage.setDisplayType(DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN);

            mImage.setSingleTapListener(new OnImageViewTouchSingleTapListener() {


                public void onSingleTapConfirmed() {

                }
            });

            mImage.setDoubleTapListener(new OnImageViewTouchDoubleTapListener() {


                public void onDoubleTap() {

                }
            });

            mImage.setOnDrawableChangedListener(new OnDrawableChangeListener() {


                public void onDrawableChanged(Drawable drawable) {

                }
            });

            //mImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.poster);
            if( null == imageMatrix ) {
                imageMatrix = new Matrix();
            } else {
                // get the current image matrix, if we want restore the 
                // previous matrix once the bitmap is changed
                // imageMatrix = mImage.getDisplayMatrix();
            }
            Bitmap imgs = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.poster);
            mImage.setImageDrawable(null);
            //mImage.setBackgroundResource(imgs, imageMatrix.isIdentity() ? null : imageMatrix, ImageViewTouchBase.ZOOM_INVALID, ImageViewTouchBase.ZOOM_INVALID);
            mImage.setImageBitmap( imgs, imageMatrix.isIdentity() ? null : imageMatrix, ImageViewTouchBase.ZOOM_INVALID, ImageViewTouchBase.ZOOM_INVALID );     

        }

}
```

Comment: try using `ImageView` to see if problem is from your code or it's from your library.

Comment: setDisplayType( DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN ).